# Using Dynamic Var with `Set` State in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a pretty common pattern in React components:

```
handleTextFieldChange(event)
{
    const name = event.currentTarget.name;
    this.setState({[name]: event.currentTarget.value})
}
```

What Javascript syntax could be used to do the same with React hooks?

i.e. something possibly along the lines of:

```
handleTextFieldChange(event)
{
    const name = event.currentTarget.name;
    this.set[name](event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use a single `useState` with a default value of an object that contains all your input values and update that like you are used to with class components.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  function onChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={state.email} name="email" onChange={onChange} />
      <input value={state.password} name="password" onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Would not we lose fine-grain control if we group every state key in a single object? Of course, that was how it was done prior to hooks

Comment: After hours of trying to make a more 'physical' conditional state work,  this 'invisible' case worked for me.  My use case was trying to make handlers for checkboxes that would exists or not exist at any time and in any amount, so if anyone is doing that (or similar), This led me to the right place.

Answer (score 14):

How about something like this?

```
function handleTextFieldChange(mySetFunction, event) {
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;
    mySetFunction(value);
}

<TextField
    placeholder="Email"
    name="passwordResetEmailAddress"
    onChange={(e) => handleTextFieldChange(setPasswordResetEmailAddress, e)}
>
    {passwordResetEmailAddress}
</TextField>
```

I've tested it and it works.

Comment: I was hesitated to do this, as there is an overhead of adding extra code, but for now, this seems to be the only way of doing it with hooks

Answer (score 10):

```
class Yup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    first: "",
    second: ""
  };

  handleTextFieldChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
    this.setState({ [name]: value });

  render() {
    const { first, second } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{first}</p>
        <p>{second}</p>
        <input type="text" name="first" onChange={this.handleTextFieldChange} />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="second"
          onChange={this.handleTextFieldChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

same with hook

```
function Yup() {
  const [{ first, second }, setState] = useState({ first: "", second: "" });

  function handleTextFieldChange({ target: { name, value } }) {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{first}</p>
      <p>{second}</p>
      <input type="text" name="first" onChange={handleTextFieldChange} />
      <input type="text" name="second" onChange={handleTextFieldChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer. The transformation from class -> hook is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can dynamically update a state for the target field by receiving an update state function as an argument in onChange function.

**Example**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const onChangeHandler = (setIdentifierState, event) => {
    setIdentifierState(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{"Email: " + email}</p>
      <p>{"Password: " + password}</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="email"
        onChange={onChangeHandler.bind(null, setEmail)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="password"
        onChange={onChangeHandler.bind(null, setPassword)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently tackled this same problem while converting my components from classes to functions. I ended up creating an object that could then point to the separate state hooks:

```js
const textStates = {};
const setTextStates= {};
for (var name of names) {
  let [textState, setTextState] = useState("");
  textStates[name] = textState;
  setTextStates[name] = setTextState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way (a slightly more dynamic solution than what @VikR offered)

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
const [video, setVideo] = useState("");

const handleChange = setter => event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    //special cases
    if (setter === setVideo) {
        setInvalidVideo(!ReactPlayer.canPlay(value))
    }

    setter(value)
}
```

Then in my code:

```
        <TextField fullWidth value={title} type="date"
                   label={t('service.ticket.add.title')}
                   placeholder={t('service.ticket.add.titlePh')}
                   onChange={handleChange(setTitle)} variant="outlined"/>
```